# Extjs grid checkbox field select all issue

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid

Extjs, i am facing an issue in gridSelectionModel of checkbox grid. When i tried to select all checkbox using grid.gridSelectionModel().selectAll(). For few records it works, but with records more than 500 it makes page not responding. i tried with suspending the events. But all the above does not work as expected.
I am using Extjs 4.2.2 version

Comment: I think this is grid.getSelectionModel() not grid.gridSelectionModel().    And It should work. Tell me one think how are you showing so many records? Did you used paging or simply you are showing all data in grid.

Comment: i have to show around 10000 records at a time. When click on a button i have to select all records. Upto 1000 records it works fine but after that it makes page not responding

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue in 4.2.2 in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11o4). The browser window freezes for quite some time.

The problem is fixed in 5.1.2 and 6.0.1.

In the docs I found that selectAll has the `suppressEvent` flag, which works out quite well (`selectAll(true)`). You would want to manually fire the selectionchange event once after working with `suppressEvent`.

Comment: Thank you it works, but the performance is very poor. it takes some time to run nearly 8000 records.

Comment: i have a quried output select with more than 10000 records , i want to set checkbox model . I tried some thing like this gridSelectionmode.select(record, true,true);

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, In my case i had to set checkbox enabled for already selected fields

```
// select the records
var selectedModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.suspendChange = true;

for (var i = 1; i < query.getCount() ; ++i)
selectionModel.select(query.getAt(i), true, true);
```